# PHP & Installation on Windows 7 with IIS 10

Tags: php, iis

I have the following configuration on my windows machine.

I have windows 7 operating system.

I downloaded the Windows Installer for PHP and installed all the required components for the same.

I also installed 'PHP Manager for IIS'.

But when I start the http://localhost/. I keep getting an error

The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: 
Connection to localhost failed.

The system returned: (101) Network is unreachable

The remote host or network may be down. Please try the request again.

Comment: It seems that your IIS server is down. Did you start your IIS server? If not, start it and check again.

Comment: I checked the IIS server, it said it was running! I checked by looking at the Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager. I restarted the same many times. It still does not work.

Comment: On which port IIS server is running?

Comment: The IIS server is running on port 80. Under IIS manager, Default Web Site, under PHP Manager, it says Information about PHP cannot be obtained due to invalid IIS configuration

Comment: It is not clear how you set up the sites. If nothing is configured to serve http://localhost then this error is expected.